# Error loading a persisted workflow

Tags: persistence, workflow-foundation-4

I have a workflow started and persisted using messaging activities.
The correlation between the Start initial command and the Stop final command works well if they're sent within few seconds.
Problems begin when the workflow is unloaded, because the following Stop message throws the following FaultException:

If LoadWorkflowByInstanceKeyCommand.AssociateLookupKeyToInstanceId is not specified, the LookupInstanceKey must already be associated to an instance, or the LoadWorkflowByInstanceKeyCommand will fail. For this reason, it is invalid to also specify the LookupInstanceKey in the InstanceKeysToAssociate collection if AssociateLookupKeyToInstanceId isn't set

Can anybody help me?
The variables inside the workflow are of types int and XDocument.
This is the code to initialize the WorkflowServiceHost:

```
WorkflowServiceHost serviceHost = new WorkflowServiceHost(myWorkflow, new Uri(serviceUri));
            ServiceDebugBehavior debug = serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceDebugBehavior>();
            if (debug == null)
            {
                debug = new ServiceDebugBehavior();
                serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(debug);
            }

            debug.IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true;
            WorkflowIdleBehavior idle = serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Find<WorkflowIdleBehavior>();
            if (idle == null)
            {
                idle = new WorkflowIdleBehavior();
                serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(idle);
            }

            idle.TimeToPersist = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
            idle.TimeToUnload = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
            var behavior = new SqlWorkflowInstanceStoreBehavior
            {
                ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WorkflowPersistence"].ConnectionString,
                InstanceEncodingOption = InstanceEncodingOption.None,
                InstanceCompletionAction = InstanceCompletionAction.DeleteAll,
                InstanceLockedExceptionAction = InstanceLockedExceptionAction.BasicRetry,
                HostLockRenewalPeriod = new TimeSpan(00, 00, 30),
                RunnableInstancesDetectionPeriod = new TimeSpan(00, 00, 05)
            };
            serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(behavior);
            serviceHost.Open();
```

Looking at the database, it seems that the workflow is never suspended.

Any help appreciated,
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure what is going on here but it sounds like there are types used in the workflow that cannot be serialized and prevent the workflow from being stored to disk. When you say "Looking at the database, it seems that the workflow is never suspended." do you really mean suspended? And why do you expect the workflow to be suspended?

What happens if you send just the start message to the workflow and wait 2 seconds? Do you get a new record in the persistence database?

Comment: For suspended, I mean that it goes to the RunnableInstancesTable table, and the value IsSuspended is set to 1 in the InstancesTable table.
The workflow can be serialized because if I add a delay, it is correctly suspended.
The problem is that after the WorkflowIdleBehavior.TimeToUnload elapsed, the workflow is not suspended and a call to the Stop operation throws the mentioned error. The error is not thrown if I send the Stop operation before the TimeToUnload timeout.
It is a long running workflow.

Comment: I realized that I made an error in the workflow definition, repeating the correlation initialization in the Stop receive activity.
Anyway, I would appreciate an explanation of the reason why the idled workflow is not in the runnableinstancestable...is it anyway serialized into the database and unloaded from memory? which policy is used?

Comment: A persisted workflow is stored in the InstancesTable table, the RunnableInstancesTable is used in recovery of workflows not when everything works just fine. Normally when a workflow is persisted it is not suspended, suspending is the result of an error when the policy is set to AbandonAndSuspend. It means the workflow will not resume automatically but needs to be resumed manually.